# Быстрое изменение скорости C# Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Доброго времени суток, у меня есть код

```
if (runtoright)
            Rg.AddForce (Vector3.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        else 
            Rg.AddForce (Vector3.forward * speed * -Time.deltaTime, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
```

runtoright меняется в зависимости от достижение правого/левого краев, но при смене краев скорость быстро становится маленькой, а мне нужно что бы как бы отбилось с такой же скорость, могу использовать transform.Translate, но мне нужно именно физически двигать объект, как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорость становится маленькой из-за того, что вы добавляете направленную силу. Т.е. сначала объект начнёт замедляться, а только потом разгоняться в противоположную сторону.

Вероятно, вам можно использовать [Vector3.MoveTowards](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html). Этот метод представляет из себя интерполяцию вектора. Т.е. он принимает три параметра - начальная позиция, конечная позиция, и нормализованное положение между ними (от 0 до 1. При 0 и ниже вернётся начальная позиция, при 1 и больше конечная).

Т.е. вы гарантировано не уйдёте дальше заданной точки. Могу предложить следующее решение:

```
public float _duration; //Время за которое вы хотите доходить от одного края до другого.

Vector3 _begin;
Vector3 _end;

float _curentTime;

void Start()
{
    _curentTime = 0;
    transform.position = _begin; // Задаем начальное положение
}

Update()
{
    _curentTime += Time.deltaTime;
    float normalize = _curentTime/duration; //узнаем какая часть времени прошла с момента начала движения в нужную сторону
    var position = Vector3.MoveTowards(_begin, _end, normalize);
    if (position == _end) // Проверяем дошли ли мы до точки. Если да - меняем конечную и начальную местами и сбрасываем время.
    {
        var cash = _end;
        _end = _begin;
        _begin = cash;
        _curentTime  = 0
    }
}
```

Comment: у меня вопрос, а где тут именно строчка с движением? потому что я только вижу присваивание, или мне нужно было самому добавить?

Comment: хотя я просто использовал if (runtoright)
   transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (transform.position, _right, Time.deltaTime * speed);
  else 
   transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (transform.position, _left, Time.deltaTime * speed);, спасибо вам за помощь

Comment: @k0vpack, да, прошу прощения) забыл присваивать. Если ответ помог в решении проблемы - отметьте его принятым, чтобы вопрос закрылся в разделе, да и другим людям сразу маякнуть)

Answer (score 0):

Если Вам необходимо двигать объект физическим движком, то необходимо использовать либо метод `rigidbody.AddForce(...)` либо свойство `rigidbody.velocity`.

В данном случае, можно, при изменении переменной `runtoright`, задавать скорость объекта противоположную текущей, а уже затем двигать объект силой.

Например, это может выглядеть так:

```
//начальная инициализация вспомогательной переменной
bool dirChanged = runtoright;

...

//проверка изменения направления и изменение скорости
if(runtoright != dirChanged )
{
    dirChanged = runtoright;
    Rg.velocity = -Rg.velocity;
}

//движение объекта силой
if (runtoright)
        Rg.AddForce (Vector3.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime,  ForceMode.VelocityChange);
    else 
        Rg.AddForce (Vector3.forward * speed * -Time.deltaTime,  ForceMode.VelocityChange);
```